# Report Server (ssrs): retrieve column name by query

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, power-bi-report-server

Would you help me, please, to retrieve column name by query.
In the report I want to show columns by condition.
I created a parameter @cols, which contains the list of column names (multiple values are allowed).
In column visibility/show or hide based on expression I added:

```
 =IIF(InStr(Join(Parameters!cols.Value, “,”), “My_col_name”)=0, true, false)
```

This works perfectly, but for each column I should insert in the row above the original column instead "My_col_name".
Since my report has hundreeds of columns, it looks annoyying.

Is there a method to simplify this task? E.g. to insert instead "My_col_name" some expression, which shows selected column name?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think the tablix control has column names so I don't think you can do this. The alternative might be to unpivot the columns in the dataset query. You query would return a column called say `colName` which would contain the name of each column and a `value` column containing the numeric data, then use a matrix to pivot them back again. You could then filter out the unwanted columns in the dataset query itself (e.g. `WHERE colName IN (@cols)` ) . it might make the report more efficient too but I guess it depends on your database table(s) design.

Comment: @AlanSchofield, thank you for the alternative: to prepare data in sql and after - to pivot data in report server. It's great for little amount of data. But hundreeds columns multiply for thousands rows, this will make report execution slower.